# Real positional string formatting?

Tags: c++, string, formatting, string-formatting, boost-format

<sup>(Note: I know of Boost.Format, I'm looking for a better way to do the following.)</sup>
First a use-case example: In some countries, you name a person by calling his / her surname first and the forename last, while in other countries it's the exact opposite.

Now, for my code, I currently solve this with Boost.Format in the following fashion:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility>

int main(){
    using namespace boost;

    int pos1 = 2, pos2 = 1;
    char const* surname = "Surname", *forename = "Forename";

    // decision on ordering here
    bool some_condition = false;

    if(some_condition)
      std::swap(pos1,pos2);

    char buf[64];
    sprintf(buf,"Hello %c%d%c %c%d%c",'%',pos1,'%','%',pos2,'%');
    // buf == "Hello %[pos1]% %[pos2]%"; with [posN] = value of posN

    std::cout << format(buf) % surname % forename;
}
```

Now, I would rather have it like this, i.e., everything in the `format` line:

```
std::cout << format("Hello %%1%% %%2%%") % pos1 % pos2 % surname % forename;
```

But sadly, that doesn't work, as I get a nice parsing exception.

Is there any library to have real positional formatting? Or even a way to achieve this with Boost.Format that I don't know of?

Comment: +1 for have the courage to show us: "int pos1 = 2, pos2 = 1;"

Comment: and the reason why you can't just `std::swap(surname, forename);` in situ is...?

Comment: @Pete: that _is_ interesting, indeed

Comment: @sehe: That reason is another good question in itself. ;) But this is just a simple case, it might get more complicated with the word ordering.

Comment: @Pete: Gotta admit, that comment made me chuckle. :)

Comment: @Xeo: ok, understood. I'll withdraw my answer as it doesn't answer the spirit of the question then

Comment: OT: thx for showing me the `<sup>` markup. Yay! More markup

Comment: @sehe: Try combining `<sup>` and `<sub>` for super-small fonts. :) Also, that's basic HTML which is supported, not markup per se.

Comment: @Xeo: well, I wasn't aware of the support in here. (Other Html-ish markup doesn't work too well on SO). Also, to nitpick my own misnomer: it should have been Markdown anyways.

Comment: What are the odds that the word ordering is the only thing you need to change? In locales with different order of the names, is "Hello" really a proper greeting? What about middle name or initial? Or titles - "Professor Dr Ing Schultz"?

Comment: @Bo: Simple example gone too simple. :( Valid claim though, but this idea is somehow fixed inside my head. You might consider user settings to reorder certain output or display. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[Karma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/tutorials/quick_start.html) is the definitive modern output formatting library.

Comment: True, but not very relevant to this question? You'd have write specific formatting rule for the respective localized formatting preferences, much like the separate format strings

Comment: After reading the motivation from Xeo, this gets my +1. Deffo most versatile. Karma will make the model/view separation easier than Boost Format. A lot. Use FUSION struct adaptation and you'll be able to 'databind' directly to your [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

Comment: @sehe : How is it not relevant to "*Is there any library to have real positional formatting?*"?

Comment: @sehe : No idea what you mean by that; in any case, the Karma generator could use a semantic action that has the localized formatting logic so only a singular grammar need exist regardless of desired output order.

Comment: @ildjam: yeah I'm with you since a while; however, I do have a feeling that we're burying the wretched conditional in a pretty lambda that we can pass off as 'metadata'. Xeo's pseudo code example shows more of a statically defined, general-purpose multi-pass formatting engine instead. No special-purpose conditionals. At all.

Comment: Karma doesn't support positional arguments or format strings at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Message Formatting](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/messages_formatting.html) part of [Boost.Locale](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/index.html) which is similar to [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).

In it you would write:

```
cout << format(translate("Hello {1} {2}!")) % forename % surname << endl;
```

And then a translator would translate the string using message catalogs:

```
msgid "Hello {1} {2}!"
msgstr "こんにちは {2}-さん!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply swap the values that you interpolating

```
std::swap(surname, forename)
```

That'll do the job. If you don't want to mess with them, have references:

```
const std::string& param1(bSwapThem? forename : surname);
const std::string& param2(bSwapThem? surname  : forename);
```

*KISS*

Comment: Okay, then this is a case of "Simple example gone too simple". :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that should be in the system locale but it doesn't look like it's currently supported.

What about the simple way?

```
   if(some_condition)
      std::cout << surname << " " << forename;
   else
      std::cout << forename << " " << surname;
```

Comment: mmmm... it seems you may have missed a bit of the discussion already :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have used ?:

```
char const* surname = "Surname", *forename = "Forename";
bool swapFlag = (some_condition) ? true : false;

std::cout << "Hello " << (swapFlag ? surname : forename) << " " << (!swapFlag ? surname : forename) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I'm starting to think I should undelete my answer to prevent too many 'me too' responses :)

Comment: Well to be honest, I haven't seen you answer before your comment ><... sorry.

Comment: nevermind, that comment wasn't addressed `'@'` you in particular

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying format recursively:

```
cout << format(str(format("%%%1%%% %%%2%%%") % pos1 % pos2)) % surname % forname;
```

However, I would recommend using something like [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) instead.